# How is it possible a variable is being used but never defined in C?

Tags: c

On line 137 in [hal.c](http://sourceforge.net/p/freakz/code/29/tree/freakz/driver/avr_at86rf/hal.c) you will see it does:

```
SPDR = data;
```

within the hal_spi_write() function.

Where is SPDR defined?

I have downloaded the entire [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freakz/files/latest/download) and done a search for "SPDR" but no luck.

Would appreciate one of the experts from the community to please weigh in.

Comment: Did you search the .h files?

Comment: Hint: it's probably going to be something like `#define SPDR (*(volatile uint8_t *)0x000f3c00)`...

Comment: Is it using implicit `int`?

Comment: @Prashant - That has to do with function calls, not lvalue assignments.

Comment: I have searched this file: http://sourceforge.net/p/freakz/code/29/tree/freakz/driver/avr_at86rf/at86rf230_registermap.h but no success.

Comment: It *might* be possible that the name is constructed by other macros (via the `##` operator).

Comment: If you can gcc the code, using the -c-save-temps flag and then examining the resulting *.i file would help track down the header in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SPDR` is not exactly a variable — it's a hardware register. Specifically, it's the SPI data register on Atmel AVR processors:

> 19.5.3. **SPDR – SPI data register**
>
> ```
>   Bit             7     6     5     4     3     2     1     0
>   0x2E (0x4E)  | MSB |     |     |     |     |     |     | LSB |  SPDR
>   Read/write     R/W   R/W   R/W   R/W   R/W   R/W   R/W   R/W
>   Initial value   X     X     X     X     X     X     X     X     undefined
> ```
>
> The SPI Data Register is a read/write register used for data transfer between the Register File and the SPI Shift Register. Writing to the register initiates data transmission. Reading the register causes the Shift Register Receive buffer to be read.

For more information, see the data sheet for the CPU you're using. The snippet above is from the [ATmega48/88/168 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2545.pdf), for instance (page 170).

Comment: But is this register name implicitly declared by the compiler?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: It's defined in a system header specific to the part in use. (For instance, it's defined in `<avr/iom168p.h>` as `_SFR_IO8(0x2E)` for the ATmega168.)

Comment: Well, there's OP's answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably included in a header file somewhere. In more advanced scenarios, you'll see variables used that are provided by the linker and loader.

After all, everything is just a symbol to the object file. You can refer to most of the variables that you can find in a binary using a tool like `nm(1)` as long as your tell the compiler about it using the `extern` keyword.

Comment: The worst is symbols defined in make files and passed in on the command line.

Comment: Jeez. I forgot about those. :)